# Web Application becomes very slow With Java

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am developing a Java Communication Gateway (CGW), where it gets data packet from GPS device, process it and store in one table called Live table(Database is running in different server - From Java CGW i called database connection through connection pool and insert data in Live table).

On the other hand, Our web application is also reading data from same Live table. Hence when Java CGW application starts web application becomes very very slow, even first page does not open. I am using SQL server 2005.

Please suggest me why it is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a thread priority problem, maybe you should take a look at that.

Comment: The table is probably getting locked by the CGW application. Hence, the query gets slowed down.

Comment: @AmitBhargava - How can i fix if it is getting locked

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti - I am having 200 thread who takes data at one time from hornetQ and push it to Live table with maximum 200 active connection using tomcat connection pooling and database is in different server, so how can we conclude that it is thread issue- since my CGW thread is running in different server and only asking connection from database server.

Comment: @Anand Normally in our apps, we do bulk updates late at night. However, this results in the risk of stale data. How often is the CGW application running?

Comment: @AmitBhargava - we get every two minute device data and we process it and store in Live table- our customers wants to view Live vision of their vehicle through web application, so we need to do operation same time - Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is a thread priority problem since reading / saving the data seems to take more processor time than expected, you could lower the thread priority by calling setPriority with a number lower than 5 in your current thread.

To get the current thread.

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
```

To know how to call it properly check out [Set Priority method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) hope this helps!

Comment: But i am calling 200 threads in different server where my CGW application is running , these thread i used to take more data to process- since we have every minute 2000 data coming from devices. For inserting/updating happens in database server with max 200 connection through connection pooling- please tell me how thread will effect the operation when i am using these 200 thread to take data from device and then insert/update to database.

Comment: I can think that your data collection processes takes a lot of CPU and when a connection (from the web server) enters to read the data you're collecting, the processor gives less importance to the incoming connection and that is what makes your browsing slow. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your architecture. I understand your collection process is in another computer, but how you'd read the data from it if is not from a network connection right?

Comment: I am using HornetQ JMS system to store all data coming from devices. HornetQ stores all data and we read data through TCP listener then we store in HornetQ, same time we have one application which is again in same server- from where we read data by 200 threads from hornetQ simultenously- every thread hits the database once get database connection object from connection pool and then insert data in Live table. all 200 threads gets database connection from connection pool and use this connection object to store data in live table and same time application also read live table only.

Comment: do you use the same connection pool for reading and writing data? maybe you're having a long wait time on the web while waiting for a connection to be released on the pool to read the data.

Comment: No i am using hornet connection object to read data from hornetQ JMS system. Only i am using Database connection object to insert data into database. and our web application same time read data from the database.

Comment: I think you are mentioning right part, while inserting into database, my CGW java has high priority than web application process, can you help me to give low importance to our CGW operation or any kind of resource distribution from SQL server to CGW and web application - kind of 50-50%, is there any mechanism like this. thanks

Comment: I am finding that in my SQLServer more than 150 connection is in suspended mode, is this the reason which uses more DB resources and block something, what would happen if suspended connection is more? will it impact on DB performance.

Comment: Check what happens if you lower the amount of connections to say, 10 or 20

Comment: when i am seeing DB performance matrix - i am finding 200 Active connection , 150 Suspended and 150 is in sleeping. Is suspended and sleeping connection- making my web application to come up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you done performance profiling of the DB server? Maybe workload of the DB server is too heavy. If Web application only reads the data, a master/slave database configuration should solve the DB server workload problem.

Comment: Could you please explain in brief- How to use profiler and how to make master slave architecture as we are storing data in live table and same time my users trying to access their vehicle through web application, please suggest me how to move forward.

Comment: MySql supports master/slave and it's pretty easy to setup. See the reference doc here: http://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/how-to-mysql-masterslave-replication/

Comment: I am finding that in my SQLServer more than 150 connection is in suspended mode, is this the reason which uses more DB resources and block something, what would happen if suspended connection is more? will it impact on DB performance.

Comment: This looks like a very possible reason. There should be a maximum allowable connection setting for your database server. If your all connections are occupied by your writing process, the web server can not get data from database. Do you correctly close database connection when your writing operation finished?

Comment: Yes we are closing connection properly, I wanted to know how suspended process hampers Database performance and how badly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

200 thread is a challenging number.

- What is the system architectural overview?
- How much memory is consumed for all of those threads.
- How do you synchronize your data/communication between threads.
- What is the hardware configuration.
- Is it necessary to use SqlServer? the jdbc:odbc bridges could be slower than jdbc:mysql.

Usually in multi-threading scenarios, communication overhead is exponential with respect to participating agents. Also, the way data is processed: same function for many data OR multiple functions / stages for multiple data types?